# CSS: animation delay on only one animation

Tags: css, css-animations

I currently have 3 animations, which I call like this:

```
animation: 225ms radius-in forwards, 
           75ms opacity-in forwards, 
          150ms opacity-out;
```

Is there a way, using pure css, to delay the "opacity-out" animation, until the radius-in animation is done?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I added a delay of 4 secs to the final animation below. For visibility purpose, I set the duration of each animation to 2 secs.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  opacity: 0.3;
  background-color: darkgray;
  animation:2000ms radius-in forwards, 2000ms opacity-in forwards, 2000ms 4000ms opacity-out forwards;
}

@keyframes radius-in {
from { border-radius: 0; }
to { border-radius: 25px; }
}

@keyframes opacity-in {
from { opacity: 0; }
to { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes opacity-out {
from { opacity: 1; }
to { opacity: 0.3; }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Seems to do the trick. Thank you! (I would upvote but I don't have enough reputation, sorry)